# Converting numeric data from text file and writing it to .con. file

Tags: visual-c++

I have to write a vc++ code for converting the data from text file to .con ,  can anyone help me please ?

Data in text file is as below

```
1,0.11,0.1,0.2,0.3
2,2.0,2.2,2.3,2.4
```

I have to omit the first number in the file , say 1 and 2, I have to write the rest into the .con file. The data in .con should be of type double

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Following a simple example writing to console.

```
using System.Globalization;

foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("TextFile1txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Splitting line `{line}`:");
    var numbers = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
    {
        double d;
        if (Double.TryParse(numbers[i], NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), out d))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Number {i} is {d}");
        }
    }
}
```

For writing to configuration instead of console see [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms134088(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms134088(v=vs.110).aspx)